# why doesn't this code do what I expect

Tags: ruby, puzzle

I'd expect this code:

```
def print_call_and_return(string, &block)
  puts string
  block.call unless !block
  "return"
end

puts print_call_and_return("parameter") do
  puts "block"
end
```

to print:

```
parameter
block
return
```

however it actually prints the following:

```
irb(main):011:0> puts print_call_and_return("parameter") do
irb(main):012:1* puts "block"
irb(main):013:1> end
parameter
return
=> nil
```

could someone explain this?

Comment: It's a really good idea to provide a much better title for your question. "why doesn't this code do what I expect" doesn't tell us ANYTHING about your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work:

```
puts print_call_and_return("parameter") { puts "block" }
```

I think the reason has to do with operator precedence. `do/end` has higher precedence than `{}` blocks.

```
puts print_call_and_return("parameter") do
  puts "block"
end
```

is the same as

```
puts(print_call_and_return("parameter")){ puts "block" }
```

Comment: do is like if and while, etc., weaker than any expression.

Answer (score 1):

print_call_and_return("parameter") prints "parameter" and returns "return"

so the output so far is "parameter"

puts print_call_and_return("parameter") does a puts on the return value, which is "return"

so the output so far is "parameter", then "return"

puts answers nil, and puts do #anything does nothing.  do is weaker than any expression, so the block applies to (puts function) do, not puts (function do).

output is as expected.

Comment: That's the answer, `puts ... do` does nothing.